# COM Object that returns SAFEARRAY(Long) causing SafeArrayTypeMismatchException

Tags: vb.net, com, safearray

I write plugins for a program that we use at work using a API Type library they provide. It is a COM object named SCAPI. The COM object was written for VB6 so when I add the reference for it it for .NET, an Interop version of it is created.

When I use the following code, it is supposed to return a SAFEARRAY(Long) as per the documentation, I get an error saying I have a SafeArrayTypeMismatchException.

```
 Dim oBag As SCAPI.PropertyBag = tempModel.PropertyBag
 Dim x = oBag.Value("Created")
```

The error is being thrown from the SCAPI.PropertyBagClass.get_Value(Object Property) function, which is part of the COM object, not something I've written. After all the research I've done, I can't seem to figure out what I need to do to get this working. I've used tlbimp.exe to get the method information but it doesn't seem to contain any [out] tags in it, even though I've used the same function oBag.Value("Name"), which returns a string value and doesn't throw an error:

```
 .method public hidebysig newslot specialname abstract virtual 
         instance object 
         marshal( struct) 
         get_Value([in] object  marshal( struct) Property) runtime managed internalcall
 {
 .custom instance void [mscorlib]System.Runtime.InteropServices.DispIdAttribute::.ctor(int32) = ( 01 00 01 00 02 60 00 00 )                         // .....`..
 } // end of method ISCPropertyBag::get_Value
```

Comment: Will your array entries be big enough to require the Long data type? Try using Integer and see if it works. I had a similar problem with VB not recognizing the data type Long.